# xml auto complete dose not work for android namespace

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am making a `CustomView` and running it and testing it for several times. after that, suddenly my layout xml auto completes for android name space disabled. just few item shows up and other item is invisible.

I've tried invalid catch and restart, remove catch folder and other files , uninstalling android studio and install again, creating new project and still dose not working.

please help me
[check this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcaJT.png)

Layout_margin and many other items dose not shows up [check this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIhez.png)

also there are no suggestions for that
[check this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEqO6.png)

Comment: Rebuild project on build tab

Comment: Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion and check whether all the req parameters are checked